# Presence indicator

Tags: office, presence-indication

We have deployed a contact list CQWP across all company machines on IE8. The presence indicators are showing, but on some machines it's showing the vertical dropdown (2007 style) and on others it's showing the new look.

I read that this indicator is associated with the version of Office installed, but this is a managed internal environment, so all computers have Office 2007.

How do we identify the root cause of this discrepancy?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do the machines with newer look have any office 2010 components installed at all?  Maybe just SP Designer 2010 or onenote 2010?

Comment: No. And even more interestingly, there's one machine we just tested with SP Designer 2010 installed but seeing the 2007 presence on the site.